# Django complex query to parent

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I am using django and I am having a little trouble figuring out how to handle complex queries to the database. I have two models:

Parent:

```
id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
name = models.CharField(max_length = 60)
category = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

And son:

```
id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
name = models.CharField(max_length = 60)
parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

Basically, I have an object with a queryset of sons, and I need to filter this queryset by certain categories of the parent. For example, filter all sons where parent category is 9, 10 or 11.

I know how to use Q to do the OR part, but I don't know how to filter by a field in the parent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
sons = Son.objects.filter(parent__category__in = [9, 10, 11]).select_related('parent')
```

You have to use `__` (double underscores) to access a `ForeignKey model's` fields.

Comment: if it helped - I will appreciate if you mark this answer as the right answer (mark gray tick to green) :) P.S. and read more about `select_related()` if you have not done this yet.

Answer (score 2):

Django offers a powerful and intuitive way to “follow” relationships in lookups.
Try this using `Q` from django.db.models
[Official Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

```
Son.objects.filter(Q(parent__cateogory__id='') | Q(parent__cateogy__name=''))
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use `Q` for this type of query. I would actually recommend keeping this simple as said in the **zen of Python**.

If you want those `Son` objects which have their parents in categories 9, 10 and 11 (since you have a `Categories` model as well, I am gonna suppose `Categories` model has a field `number` having respective category numbers), perform this query :

`sons = Son.objects.filter(parent__category__number__in=[9,10,11])`

One caveat however is, if you have to get `parent` object of each `Son` object in `sons` Queryset (here, taking the first `Son` object), you have to do `sons.first().parent` which hits the database with one more query because Querysets are lazily evaluated.

To prevent this from happening, and fundamentally keeping database hits limited, do the below query (only if you are sure you'll need `parent` object of `Son`s) :

```
sons = Son.objects.filter(parent__category__number__in=[9,10,11]).select_related('parent')
```

This will pre-populate `parent` for each `Son` object in `sons Queryset`.

> Also, Models are named singular, so I would recommend changing `Categories` to `Category`

Comment: Right, this is quite useful. So basically, select_related should be used only if one needs access to the parent, right?